# Why can't I use lodash's remove() function?

Tags: php, npm, lodash, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5.  I've run `npm install` and `npm run dev` and generally I have a good working environment with running Javascript, but I've been caught out while trying to use lodash's `remove()` function to remove an element from an array.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var evens = _.remove(array, function(n) {
    return n % 2 == 0;
});
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
TypeError: _.remove is not a function
```

Lodash is loaded in `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`.

```
window._ = require('lodash');
```

Other lodash methods works fine.

```
_.each([1, 2], function(n) {
    console.log(n);
});
```

Any idea why I can't use `.remove()`?

Comment: What version of lodash in located inside your package.json?

Comment: laravel-mix has a dependency of "lodash": "^4.17.4" inside of its package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I'm also using Laravel [Spark](https://spark.laravel.com/).  Spark does not use `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` and loads its own bootstrap at `vendor/laravel/spark/resources/assets/js/spark-bootstrap.js` instead.

Spark's bootstrap actually requires the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) package instead of [lodash](https://lodash.com/), hence the confusion.

```
window._ = require('underscore');
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you explicitly required lodash instead of relying on global identifier? `import _ from 'lodash';` should suffice in every module where you want to use lodash.

Comment: The Laravel and Spark frameworks specifically set and use `window._`, which is of course global.  I just wanted to reuse the existing instance.  I'm personally happy to use underscore but yes, importing lodash to another variable is an option.